# Take Page Size Value from Config file in EnableQuery Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, odata

I want to fetch page size value from the app settings file and use it on the controller attribute `[EnableQuery(PageSize = 5)]` instead of hardcoding.

```
 public class PersonController : ODataController
 {
     public string pageSize;

     public PersonController(IPersonService personService, IOptions<Configurations> configurations, ILoggingService loggingService)
     {
         _personService = personService;
         _configurations = configurations.Value;
         _loggingService = loggingService;
         pageSize = _configurations.PageSize;
     }

     [HttpGet("/persons/")]
     //[EnableQuery(PageSize = 5)] Works
     [EnableQuery(PageSize = pageSize)] // Doesn't work
     public ActionResult<IEnumerable<person>> Get()
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: try to use [EnableQuery(PageSize = _configurations.PageSize)], have you seen that _configurations.PageSize in constructor  is taking value from config which you added?

Comment: @RajeshP It doesn't works.

Comment: are you able to get this value _configurations.PageSize in constructor ?

Comment: @RajeshP yes I can see the value which I have set in app settings.

Comment: ok, here we have two options to achieve your requirement

Comment: option 1 and 2 is ?

Comment: I have added 2 options in Answer section as I can't able to add lengthy code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

With discussion in the comments sections we can access the _configurations.PageSize in approaches.

option 1 if possible:

```
 public ActionResult<IEnumerable<person>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<person> options)
{
        int pageSize = int.Parse(_configurations.PageSize);
       
                    
        var personsquery = Get the data from your service with Queryable
        var result = options.ApplyTo(personsquery,pageSize);

        return Ok(result);
 }
```

Option 2 Custom Attribute:

```
//This is new new attribute so place this code under appropriate folder in your //application

public class PageSizeFromConfigAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public PageSizeFromConfigAttribute(string appsettingskey)
    {
        var pageSize = GetPageSizeFromConfig(appsettingskey);
        PageSize = pageSize;
    }

    private int GetPageSizeFromConfig(string appsettingskey)
    {        
        return int.Parse(_configurations[appsettingskey]);
    }
}

 [HttpGet("/persons/")]
 //[EnableQuery(PageSize = 5)] Works
 //[EnableQuery(PageSize = pageSize)] // Doesn't work
 [PageSizeFromConfig(nameof(Configurations.PageSize))] //try this
 public ActionResult<IEnumerable<person>> Get()
 {
 }
```

Comment: In option One 

options.Top = pageSize;

 Compiler Error Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only, did you get the same error.

Comment: send pagesize to options.ApplyTo(personsquery,pageSize)